# Why does this flat plane has weird shading ? (Cycles)

Tags: texturing, shaders, lighting

Since upgrading to 4.0 all the flat planes that I make have this weird shading on them. It's always reflections converging into the center of the plane. I still can't figure out the source of this problem. Tried changing the HDRI, fixing the normals, adding geometry. Nothing works, any clue ?

NB: The texture is imported from Quixel Bridge (I adjusted the messy nodes that come with it aswell.)

[image: Flat plane weird shading]

Comment: Good that you figured it out yourself. Because the beginning of your question reads "all the flat planes that I make". I can imagine a lot of flat planes, not using any textures or if I use textures not using Quixel Bridge for them. So it would have been hard to figure out what causes this issue in "all" flat planes without clarification what these planes have in common or an example file to check out what's going on there.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by dropping down the Anisotropic value to 0 on the specular tab. Quixel Bridge does import textures with 1.45 in Anisotropic.